# How the value of an int being printed as a char?

Tags: c, printf

In below program ,How is `int` being converted into `char` by `printf()`? Is it being demoted implicitly?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()   
{ 
    int c=2;
    printf("%c",c);

}
```

Comment: `int main()`--> `int main(void)`

Answer (score 3):

The code is working fine! You will just get the ASCII character for c. 
Let´s look on another example:

```
int c;
for (c = 97; c < 123; c++)
{
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

This code would generate the following output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

If the value of c is greater than the biggest value of char the output just starts from the begin. This means c = 1 would generate the same output as c = 257.

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
  printf("%c",c);
```

works, because, as per the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, *The `fprintf()` function*, the `%c` format specifier,

> `c`
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted to an
> `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

So, the value held by `c` will get converted to an `unsigned char`, which then will be printed out using `%c` format specifier.

Comment: I believe that all parameters in the valist for printf will be promoted to int according to the standard in any case, so passing a char into printf would also convert it to an int.

You are lucky that these types are the same though. If you passed in a long int and passed in multiple variables you would have a real mess on your hands. Try it and see how spectacularly it breaks.

As Sourav is saying, passing in an incorrect type into printf is dangerous business.

Comment: Is this the case here? I mean, stuff like `printf("%c", 65);` is valid right? So shouldn't it be UB because the OP is trying to print an unprintable character and not because the types are different?

Comment: @CoolGuy Also, AFAIK, It is never UB for an attempt to print an unprintable character. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I tried `printf("%c", 65);` and neither GCC nor clang raised a warning. Also, `%c` expects an `int`. This can be verified by the warning *warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’* when using `printf("%c\n", "a");`

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, it expects `int`, but also notice _"the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written."_

Comment: @Cobusve Concerning "all parameters in the valist for printf will be promoted to int ".  All arguments go through the usual _default argument promotions_ including `float` --> `double`, `char` --> `int` ( or rarely `unsigned`), `long` --> `long`.

Comment: @Cool Guy `\2` is "printable" by `printf()`.  It is likely a control character and may not render any discernible out on a screen.  It would certainly make a 1 byte output file should output be re-directed to a file.  It is not UB.

Comment: @Cobusve OP's did not pass an incorrect type to `printf()`. With `printf("%c",c)`, `printf()` expected and did receive an `int`. There is no issue here concerning mis-matched types and format specifiers.

Comment: My point was simply that the question does not make sense. There is no special "demotion" happening to the int to get it onto the char. If you passed in a char it would also end up as an int. This means printf is not doing anything special to convert the int into a char, it does the same thing it does for a char.

Comment: @Chux, yes - the standard rules of promotion will be applied to all arguments. I only listed the one applicable to char and int. I could have been more complete. Also I agree that he did not pass in the wrong type here and I did not mean to imply that, but the point I was making is that types do not get magically converted and if AFTER the promotion the types do not match you will have a real mess. The best advice is to pass in the correct/matching type. The standard clearly states that if the types do not match (After promotion is applied) the behavior is UB

Comment: Perhaps what I can add is the answer to the implied question, how can the compiler EVER convert an int to a char, because that is how printf will have to do this internally. And the answer to that is the same way it would do if you did char c = (char)i; where i is an int. And the correct answer is that it will depend on the definition of char on your platform, but most likely it will take the lower 8 bits, or sometimes char is 16 or even 32 bits on the platform and then it does nothing to it ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83583/discussion-between-chux-and-cobusve).